# Adjusting the position of Navigation Bar Items in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I'm currently designing a Navigation Bar in my storyboard and I wanted to bring my two right side navigation buttons closer together.

How would I go about this? All I have right now is just a regular view controller with a navigation bar on it and two buttons.

I do have my two buttons connected to my ViewController code so I would have no problem doing it programmatically or in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option: add a view as the single item in that position, and then add your buttons to that view.

Comment: I was looking at another question on here and found this. 

`let positiveSpacer: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        positiveSpacer.width = +10
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([positiveSpacer, composeButton], animated: false)`. 

Is this what you meant by a "fixed space item?"

Comment: @EricWalier yes, though with a negative width, and between the two buttons. Thought you could do it in interface builder directly as well, but it apparently doesn't want to...

Comment: I have a search and a compose button. Would I go about it like this? `let negativeSpacer: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil) negativeSpacer.width = -10 self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([searchButton, negativeSpacer, composeButton], animated: false)`

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work. I tried troubleshooting but other variations didn't seem to work either

Comment: @EricWalier indeed, it's not working with negative widths (it works with positive ones). So you'll need to include the items in a container view, where you'll be able to fully control the layout.